# Trigger lazy initializer again in Swift by setting property to nil

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, swift

I want a lazily-initialized property whose initializer I can invoke again if I set the property to nil.

If I define my property this way:

```
lazy var object = { /*init code*/ }()
```

...and later invoke the property, the initializer is triggered once. However, if I set `object` to nil later in my program, the initializer is not invoked again. How can I do that in Swift?

I looked into computed properties but they don't actually store values, so whenever I invoke the variable, the computation or initialization always occurs. I want to compute only whenever the property is nil.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The lazy property initializer is responsible of initializing the property the first time it is accessed in read mode. Setting to nil has no effect on the initialization status - it's just a valid value the property stores.

You can mimic a lazy initialization with 3 properties:

- a private initializer, implemented as a computed property (or a closure if you prefer)
- a private backing property, storing the actual value
- a non private property, which is the one you actually use in your code

The code looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private var _myPropInitializer: Int {
        return 5
    }

    private var _myProp: Int?

    var myProp: Int? {
        get {
            if self._myProp == nil {
                self._myProp = self._myPropInitializer
            }
            return _myProp!
        }
        set {
            _myProp = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

- the initializer property returns a computed value for the variable when it needs to be initialized, which is the `5` integer in the above example
- `myProp` is an optional integer (to be able to store a `nil`):

  - on set, it will store the new value in the `_myProp` property
  - on get, if `_myProp` is `nil`, it invokes the initializer, assigning it to `_myProp`, and it returns its value

If you want to reuse that pattern, it's better to put everything in a class:

```
class Lazy<T> {
    private let _initializer: () -> T
    private var _value: T?
    var value: T? {
        get {
            if self._value == nil {
                self._value = self._initializer()
            }
            return self._value
        }
        set {
            self._value = newValue
        }
    }

    required init(initializer: () -> T) {
        self._initializer = initializer
    }
}
```

Note: a `struct` is not usable because setting a property inside a property getter is not allowed, whereas in a class it is.

Then you can use it as follows:

```
class MyTestClass {
    var lazyProp: Lazy<Int>

    init() {
        self.lazyProp = Lazy( { return 5 } )
    }
}
```

Some tests in playground:

```
var x = MyTestClass()
x.lazyProp.value // Prints {Some 5}
x.lazyProp.value = nil
x.lazyProp._value // Prints nil
x.lazyProp.value // Prints {Some 5}
```

The downside is that you have to access to the actual property as `x.lazyProp.value` and not as `x.lazyProp`.

Comment: Excellent answer, with pretty good example of generic type use

Answer (score 3):

Here's a lazy pattern I use when your object can only ever be `nil` or a computed value. It requires only 2 properties:

```
var todayPredicate: NSPredicate! {
    set {
        guard newValue == nil else {return} // could throw here if required
        self._todayPredicateLazyBacker = nil
    }
    get {
        guard self._todayPredicateLazyBacker == nil else {return self. _todayPredicateLazyBacker}

        // construct your today predicate
        let predicate = ...

        self._todayPredicateLazyBacker = predicate
        return self._todayPredicateLazyBacker
    }
}
private var _todayPredicateLazyBacker: NSPredicate?
```

`todayPredicate` is constructed only once when it is read for the first time (lazy).

So why would you ever want to set `todayPredicate` to nil? In this example you are probably observing for the day changing because `todayPredicate` must always represent today. In your observer code you would simply do this, for example...

```
self.todayPredicate = nil
self.loadEvents()
```