# Lazy loading optional property that maybe nil later

Tags: ios, swift

In Objective-C, with lazy init, I can set any `@property` to `nil` and it will be re-created when I call its `getter`.

However, in Swift, with `lazy` modifier, it doesn't work .
Tested it with this code:

```
class SomeClass {
    lazy var optionalVar: String? = {
        return "abc"
    }()

    func checkVar() {
        println(optionalVar!)
    }
}

let instance = SomeClass()
instance.checkVar()
//instance.variable = nil
instance.checkVar()
```

When `variable` set to `nil`, it will not be re-initialized. Therefore, the next line of code triggers run-time error.

How can I make my Swift code works as in Objective-C ? 
Thanks.

----------------
edit: add more code

```
class SomeClass {
    var optionalVar: String?

    func checkVar() {
        println(optionalVar!)
    }

    func createVar() -> String {
        if let tempVar = optionalVar {
            return tempVar
        } else {
            println("create optional")
            return "123"
        }
    }
}

let instance = SomeClass()
instance.optionalVar = instance.createVar()
instance.checkVar()
instance.optionalVar = nil
instance.optionalVar = instance.createVar()
instance.checkVar()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger lazy initializer again in Swift by setting property to nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760088/trigger-lazy-initializer-again-in-swift-by-setting-property-to-nil)

Comment: Yeah, I did read that question, along with a few others of the same topic. Basically, the answers in these questions are mimic objective-C solution. I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Unfortunately lazy is for one-time initialization. What about using my `Lazy` class whose code is in the linked question?

Comment: That's a good solution, really. However, I want to get familiar with the language first, so I will use a traditional way. I'm thinking create many `methods` for each `var`. Then instead of set them to `nil`, I'll just call the var's "init method", what do you think ? Is that good ?

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Comment: @Antonio I added an example in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65774/discussion-between-antonio-and-pham-hoan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what already suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760088/trigger-lazy-initializer-again-in-swift-by-setting-property-to-nil), the most elegant alternate solution I can propose is to intercept when the property is set to nil, and override the assignment with a default value:

```
class SomeClass {
    private var _optionalVar: String?

    var nonoptionalVar: String? {
        get { return _optionalVar }
        set { _optionalVar = newValue == nil ? "123" : newValue }
    }

    init() {
        self.nonoptionalVar = nil
    }
}
```

There is one downside though: you have to remember to explicitly set the property to nil in the initializer (otherwise the property will be left at its default initial value, which is `nil`)